# Meteor: Autoform afQuickField not displaying proper when inline with another element using bootstrap

Tags: css, meteor, twitter-bootstrap-3, meteor-autoform

I am trying to get two afQuickField text fields to display in the same line and from any example I have seen, which is not very many out there, I can not get them to look correct.  I have a client form, it has address etc in it.  I am trying to get the Suite fiel and the City field to display inline on the same line.  I am also trying to get the State and Zip fields on the same line.

I can accomplish this if I have my bootstrap grid set to col-md-6 so that this form is in half the page.  The will be inline however they will not be the full width of the col as all the other text fields are and it looks funny.  But what I really want is for this form to be in a col-md-4.  When I do this it seperates both of these and puts them on seperate lines but again neither are the full length like other text fields.  I have attached pictures here of both senarios.

What I am looking for is to have these two fields lineup to be the same width as the other fields around them so they don't stand out like a sore thumb.

I have attached a plnkr of my html doc as well as pasted the applicable code below.

```
{{#autoForm collection="customers" id="insertCustomer" type="insert"}}
<div class="row customerForm">
    <div class="col-md-4 rcorners">
        <!--    ************************************************
                *****   Customer Name and address fields  ***********
                ************************************************ -->

        {{> afQuickField name='customerName' template="bootstrap3-horizontal" 
             input-col-class="col-sm-12 padL-0"  label-class="sr-only"
             afFieldInput-placeholder="schemaLabel"}}

        {{> afQuickField name='customerAddress' template="bootstrap3-horizontal" 
             input-col-class="col-sm-12 padL-0"  label-class="sr-only"
             afFieldInput-placeholder="schemaLabel"}}           

        <div class="form-inline">

                {{> afQuickField name='customerSuite' 
                    template="bootstrap3-inline" label-class="sr-only" 
                    afFieldInput-placeholder="schemaLabel"}}

                {{> afQuickField name='customerCity' 
                    template="bootstrap3-inline" label-class="sr-only" 
                    afFieldInput-placeholder="schemaLabel"}}


        </div>


        <div class="form-inline">

                {{> afQuickField name='customerState' 
                    template="bootstrap3-inline" label-class="sr-only" 
                    afFieldInput-placeholder="schemaLabel"}}

                {{> afQuickField name='customerZip' 
                    template="bootstrap3-inline" label-class="sr-only" 
                    afFieldInput-placeholder="schemaLabel"}}


        </div>


        {{> afQuickField name='customerPhone1' template="bootstrap3-horizontal" 
            input-col-class="col-sm-12 padL-0"  label-class="sr-only"
             afFieldInput-placeholder="schemaLabel"}}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/y0v2Xltdfs01wqZS5ZIg

[image]

[image]